# Is this a correct expression of amounts and percentages?

Tags: grammar

There is a sentence I am trying to write in which I have to say 72 percent of women were able to imagine spatially to a very high extent, 41 percent were able to do so to a high extent, and so forth. Is the following composition correct grammatically, with specific emphasis on the way *level* is used?

> With respect to the question concerning women’s imagination of architectural space via expressing or retelling memories, results showed that 50 percent in a very high level, 72 percent in a high level, 41 percent in a medium level, 11 percent in a low level, and 4 percent in a very low level were capable of imagining space via hearing about visual characteristics

Comment: Perhaps, try *"... results showed varying proportions of women who were capable of the mentioned task to different levels of extent: 50 percent at a very high level, 72 percent at a high level, ..."* The basic idea is to tell the reader what we are going to talk about first, and tell them the data later. I'd also like to suggest keeping all the terms consistent. Instead of switching between extent and level, choose one and stick with it. Putting writing style aside, I think your numbers either don't add up or somewhat aren't in order. (72% passed the high-level, but only 41% the medium?)

Comment: Either the percentages should add up to about 100 percent, or they should monotonically increase as the selection criterion becomes easier.

Comment: In general, I would use "at" or "a" with level and not "in". "The results showed that 50% performed at a very high level." or "72% of the test group had results that showed a high level of spatial imagination..."

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is a bit off. It's hard to tell without more context, but "in a very high level" should probably be "in the very high-level group", or maybe "at a high level". I'm also not clear on what "imagination... via expressing or retelling memories" means. "Results" could use either an article or a possessive. The sentence is hard to understand because it's so long. You probably shouldn't put the verb so close to the end. Here's what your sentence sounds like to me:

1. There's a question concerning women's imagination of architectural space. This imagination somehow relates to expressing or retelling memories.
2. The women are divided into several groups according to their level of some ability -- very high, high, etc. I'm not sure what the ability is -- are you referring back to imagination via expressing or retelling memories? Or are you referring forward to imagining space via hearing about visual characteristics?
3. Some fraction of each group (50% of the very high level group, 72% of the high level group, etc.) was able to imagine a space by hearing about its visual characteristics.
4. #2 and #3 address (in some way) the question mentioned in #1.

Without more context it's hard to suggest improvements. At a guess, you might mean something like this:

> The next question concerns women's ability to imagine architectural spaces after hearing about their visual characteristics. Our results showed that 50% of women have a very high level of this ability, while 72% have a high level, 41% have a medium level, 11% have a low level, and 4% have a very low level.

Alternately, if you meant to refer to two separate kinds of ability, you might mean this:

> The next question concerns whether women's ability to imagine architectural spaces after expressing or retelling memories relates to their ability to imagine architectural spaces after hearing about their visual characteristics. In the group of women with a very high level of memory-related imagination, 50% were capable of hearing-related imagination. 72% of the high-level group, 41% of the medium-level group, 11% in the low-level group, and 4% in the very low-level group were also capable of this task.

These are not the greatest examples. "Memory-related imagination" is probably wrong, but my point is that it might help to have a shorter way of saying "ability to imagine architectural spaces after expressing or retelling memories".